# Black ignores skip-string-normalization flag

Tags: python, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, python-black

In my `pre-commit` configuration I have `black` version `19.10b0` and in `pyproject.toml` I have line:

`skip-string-normalization = true`

So my strings don't get double quotes normalized.

But then I run `pre-commit autoupdate`, `black` version upgrades to `20.8b1` and all strings get normalized to double quoted variant.

I don't understand why this happens, **any reasons for that?**

`black` [changelog](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/change_log.html) have nothing about strings or quotes between this two versions.

Also if I explicitly pass `pyproject.toml` to `black` (using `args: [--config=./pyproject.toml]` line) it still normalizes strings

Comment: show all of your configuration files -- we can't see your screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is given in [a black issue](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1634)

It was a bug.

But it will be shipped to release soon